# Have more than a million people had their whole genomes sequenced by the end of 2018?

Tags: medical-science, genetics

The news article https://www.wired.com/story/whole-genome-sequencing-cost-200-dollars/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190704063009/https://www.wired.com/story/whole-genome-sequencing-cost-200-dollars/)) published on 2018-11-18 claims that

> Today, slightly more than a million people have had their whole genomes sequenced.

Aside from the fact that "whole genomes sequenced" doesn't mean that 100% of the genome is sequenced but rather ~95% ([Psst, the human genome was never completely sequenced. Some scientists say it should be](https://www.statnews.com/2017/06/20/human-genome-not-fully-sequenced/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190704063120/https://www.statnews.com/2017/06/20/human-genome-not-fully-sequenced/))), is the claim true?

Answer (score 2):

## Probably but it's hard to be certain.

It's hard to say exactly because not all whole human genome sequencing data goes into research databases, there's a number of national databases and many research institutions with their own datasets while at the same time some databases have overlaps, re-using the same individuals data.

Looking specifically whole human genome sequencing, not snp-chip or exome data:

As of Apr.25.18, from the Broad Institute

https://www.broadinstitute.org/news/broad-institute-sequences-its-100000th-whole-human-genome-national-dna-day

> In a dramatic sign of the surge of genomic information available for research around the world, on National DNA Day the Broad Institute of MIT and Harvard sequenced its 100,000th whole human genome, adding to a global total **that is approaching one million.**